# Graphing parametric equation software? Desmos/Mathematica/ other math software?

Tags: parametric, math-software, mathematica, wolfram-alpha, desmos

I want to view what the graph of, for example,

$x=\sin t,\quad y = \sin(10t)$

looks like, but not as a static graph $\ y=f(x),\ $ but rather one where we can see the movement of the point on the $\ x-y\ $ graph

$(\ x(t),\ y(t)\ ) = (\ \sin t,\ \sin(10t)\ )\ $

as $\ t\ $ varies, starting at a specified time, e.g. $\ t=0\ $ and then seeing as a video how this point moves with $\ t\ $ increasing from $\ t=0.$

I'm sure I could program this with Python or something, but is there already an option for this with the free versions of Desmos or Mathematica/ WolframAlpha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desmos can handle this for you. Here's an example of the parametric equation that you've described: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fcivlr8pll

Here's a short description of the code as well.

Writing a pair of parametric equations $(x(t), y(t))$ in Desmos will automatically parameterize the curve for $t\in[0,1]$. This will be a static curve, but you can make it dynamic by including another parameter (I call it $s$ in my program) and reparameterizing $(x(t), y(t))$ for $t \in [0,s]$. Finally, you can demonstrate where a particle is along this trajectory by including the line $(x(s), y(s))$.

I find Desmos incredibly handy for visualizing paramtric equations. If, for example, you want to study parametric equations in the complex plane, I would suggest using Desmos. Here's a more complicated example of what Desmos can handle: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6o1a3cx47b.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution in `Mathematica`

```
x[t_] := Sin[t];
y[t_] := Sin[10t];
curve = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t,0,10}];
Animate[Show[{curve, Graphics[{PointSize[0.025], Point[{x[u], y[u]}]}]}], {u, 0, 10}, AnimationRate -> 0.2]
```